# A bash script to reverse the array

Tags: bash

Here is the code that I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the size of array: "
read s
echo "Enter the elements of array: "
for (( i=0; $i<$s; i++ ))
do
    read a[$i]
done
j=`expr $s - 1`
for (( i=0; $i<$j; i++ ))
do
    temp = ${a[$i]}
    a[$i] = ${a[$j]}
    a[$j] = $temp
    j = `expr $j - 1`
done

echo "The reverse array is"
for (( i=0; $i<$s; i++ ))
do
    echo ${a[$i]}
done
```

And I'm getting the following errors

```
/home/2.sh: line 12: temp: command not found
/home/2.sh: line 13: a[0]: command not found
/home/2.sh: line 14: a[2]: command not found
/home/2.sh: line 15: j: command not found
/home/2.sh: line 12: temp: command not found
/home/2.sh: line 13: a[1]: command not found
/home/2.sh: line 14: a[2]: command not found
/home/2.sh: line 15: j: command not found
```

I was trying to swap the first element with the last element and so on, but the error says temp command not found. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's the blanks around the `=`.

Comment: my bad, I never knew the blanks mattered here. It's working now after removing them. Thanks